# How to offer visitors a "view all with tag X" option?

Tags: solspace, search, tags

After wrestling with categories for too long as a way of organising a gallery, I've ditched that and gone to tags instead (using the Solspace module). But I am stuck on one point of presentation on the gallery index page: is there a good way of offering visitors an easy way to view all images tagged with X without having a massive tag cloud of all available tags displayed? Can tags be tied into a simple search so that they can just input the tag they want to look at?

The gallery uses a one image = one entry setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the **`{exp:tag:entries}`** tag to do this:

http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/entries/

This will allow you to display a list of channel entries associated with a particular tag.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, I wasn't quite clear enough. What I wanted to solve was a way to present that information to someone who comes to my gallery index and thinks "How can I see all images tagged with Tyrion Lannister?" I don't want to present a massive list of all available tags on the index, but I am not sure how to offer a user-friendly way for someone to look for all images tagged with any given tag. Unless I can setup a search box that ties into the tag system?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the normal {exp:tag:cloud} tag.
But list the results in a javascript array/object instead of the usual html output.

Using one of many autocomplete javascript plugins, you could make a simple search.